# Is this really a good audit question?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this first post audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10434611) by downvoting it.

It seems that the exception was good enough for others to solve the issue and I saw other meta questions indicating that a short question is perfectly fine if it contains enough information, so I wasn't sure if it should be closed.

And while I accept that my action might not have been the best to take (although I was planning to write a follow-up comment), I certainly disagree that this is a "high quality post".

It lacks proper spelling/punctuation, the title is merely a copy of the error message, there are no indications of any previous efforts to solve the problem and overall it doesn't look like the OP has tried to put any significant effort into writing his question.

To quote the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down):

> When should I vote down?
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

What am I missing?

An image for the lazy ones.
[image: Failed audit]

Comment: @Drew: I'm not focussing on the ability to solve the question, but more on the sloppiness and the "high quality post" label. That doesn't change when you are an Android developer or click through.

Comment: @Marvin they throw around upvotes like candy (and rarely downvote) in the Android tag, so yes that does come into the equation. I do not agree that it is a good audit, while not necessarily a horrible question, it isn't worth the score it has. You just have to realize that the audit system, like any system, is not perfect. If you don't want to fail audits, you should be clicking through to the actual post on questions whose technology you are not familiar with.

Comment: I approach every presentation in a queue with the mindset of "It is a trick". That one you got was quite crafty so to speak. But before I cast anything into the darkness of ill-repute, I click through. In fact, before I do anything I click through. I know Servy and I went around and around on this one time. Here is a great example

Comment: Yes, valid points. Still, this is not about cheating the audit system (I agree that not skipping that one would be my bad), but about the question being used as an audit question. If the current consensus is to ignore such audits (I didn't read all of meta), then I'm fine with that, but I wanted to hear some opinions first.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. " seems pretty applicable to me, and if I had've seen this audit question I also would have failed it (I would have voted to close and also downvoted).

Comment: @sevenseacat: Wasn't sure about that because apparently the problem statement was clear enough for several other people. And it probably also helps other readers as you usually just google the exception message and are able to solve it with the provided answers. Open for discussion, though.

Comment: This is clearly not a good audit.  That post certainly merits a downvote, and now that it has one, it will never be an audit again.  To be honest, I wouldn't even bother trying to cheat the audit system as everyone else is telling you to do.  Bad audits like this are pretty rare.  If you fail an audit every now and again by doing the right thing you're almost certainly not going to actually get banned, and in the unlikely event that you do, a quick call out to a mod is likely to get it reversed if you really are doing your job well.

Comment: Remember to always be a jerk when reviewing other people's work and you'll fit in great with the review folks.